# Bigcommerce API blog posts

Tags: php, api, rest, curl, bigcommerce

Having trouble testing out the legacy basic auth api...

I want to mature this into nodejs or php, for a blog interface, but I can't seem to get the cURL working properly.

I believe I am following their [docs](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/blog/posts)... but who knows.

```
curl --request POST \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -u "user:key" \
    -d '{"title": "title", "content": "content"}' \
    https://myteststoreurl.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/blog/posts
```

I get an empty response when I attempt the following with my person info added in...

When I run

```
curl --request GET \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -u "user:key" \
    https://myteststoreurl.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/blog/posts
```

I get all current posts, correctly. But POST will not work. Also, when updating a post with PUT, it removes the post from the interface but does send the change which I can verify by running the get request.

Any Bigcommerce experts to help out here??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing this from windows and where single quote makes the problem. Change your `-d` values.

```
-d "{title\": \"title\", \"content\": \"content\"}"
```

Also add the `-v` parameter to see what is curl sending when you perform the request.

Comment: @Seth what does the `-v` returned?

Comment: do I pass `-v` before --request or after `-H, -u`??

Comment: At anywhere, try at the end! It doesn't matter.

Comment: Marking as correct since it did in fact lead me to my answer, which is posted  below

Answer (score 2):

This is actually an internal server issue with Bigcommerce API. Even when you type the correct curl command, you receive a 500 error. When running verbose, typing `-v`, you'll notice.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a syntax error to me. On you d value when posting the initial double quote for title is on the wrong side of the curly brace.
Try this.

```
curl --request POST \ 
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
    -u "user:key" \ 
    -d '{"title": "title", "content": "content"}' \ 
    https://myteststoreurl.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/blog/posts
```

Comment: I did indeed have a typo, but POST is still not adding data to the db. I assume this is an issue with their API.

Answer (score 0):

Try the same request with something like Advanced REST client (Chrome app) 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

If you are still getting the same error most likely it's a Bigcommerce API side issue.

[image]

Comment: That's a great extension.